# AJAX method not posting to web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have this method that uses AJAX to post data from a form to a web method in the C# backend. Unfortunately, the method is not being hit. I did my research and all accessible resources states that these are the required AJAX options for passing form data to a web method.

Can somebody help me understand why this is not working?

**Note: Application is asp.net webforms**

```html
<input type="file" id="uploader" />
```

```
var fileUpload = $("#uploader").get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;
var fileData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    console.log(files[i]);
}


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Pagename.aspx/method",
    data: fileData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
})
```

Comment: What is the response from the server?

Comment: There are no error responses or responses at all. The method is not being hit and browser console doesn't contain an failure details @David

Comment: So the AJAX request just hangs indefinitely?  Or is it not being requested in the first place?

Comment: Its just not posting to the web method at all. I have several ajax requests in this application but the only one that is not working is this one which contains contentType: false and processData: false.

Comment: Then what *is* it doing?  In your browser’s debugging tools what is the request/response info for this in the network tab?  If the request isn’t being made at all then it sounds like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you try to add a console.log() somewhere to confirm the ajax is being called?

Comment: ```` $.ajax({
              url: 'Pagename.aspx/method',
              type: 'post',
              data: fileData,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function(response){
              
              },
           });         check here---  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Couple more things: should not be a comma at end of processData; should be a semicolon at the end of the ajax method; (should be a success callback). Is there a ScriptManager on the page?

Comment: I was playing around with this and got weird results until I added `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the changes I made to at least get it to return a response. I did not work with the file upload at all. See if this gets it going.

Also note the use of JSON.stringify() on the 'data' line.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.aspx/method",
    data: JSON.stringify(fileData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string method()
{
    return "success";
}
```